# the nonexistence of the minimum of max(|a/b-1|,|a/(b+c)|)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I want to prove that this formula ||f-r||=max(|a/b-1|,|a/(b+c)|) does not have a minimum? for a/b=1

Answer (score 0):

Since a/b = 1, the maximum is |a/(b+c)| and the minimum is 0.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but I mean the minimum of ||f-r||, and I want to show that no minimum exists.

Comment: As ||f-r|| = max(|a/b-1|,|a/(b+c)|) the minimum of |f-r|| is still 0.

Comment: me too I find it 0, but the professor says: If you choose a/b=1, then you can do something with parameter c to show that no minimum exists.

Comment: Of course |a/(b+c)| has no minimum, which is superflous as it is always larger than |a/b-1|.

Comment: how you find that |a/(b+c)| has no minimum or it is evident ?? or what we should do for c to prove that there is no minimum? thank you so much

Comment: Sent c off to infinity.

Comment: when c goes to infinity,  |a/(b+c)| goes to 0 , right ? how it does not have a minimum ? sorry for a lot of question, and thank you for the help

Comment: It never gets there.

Comment: can you explain more? I didn't understand how